# PDF Reader that allow for searching for spaces (" R ")

Tags: pdf, search, pdf-reader

How can I readily locate references to the R programming language in a paper (PDF) that is 500 pages long?

Foxit reader and Adobe Acrobat Reader both ignore spaces in the search box, so " R " (without the quotes) is treated as "R"

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also works with Adobe Acrobat Reader.

1. From the menu go to ***Edit*** > ***Advanced Search*** OR <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
2. Input what word or phrase would you like to search for including space e.g. `R`
3. Check Whole words only
4. Search ...

You'll find the results like shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Awesome.  Thankyou!